# ASP.NET Core 3.1 HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate or HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a bit confused about which I should be using. In `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpAbstractions`, I am seeing that `ClientCertificate` is a property of `ConnectionInfo`, while `GetClientCertificateAsync` is method of `ConnectionInfo`. Both are publicly accessible, and I don't see any guidance on which one I should actually be using. Is there one that is generally preferred over the other?

Comment: Looking at the [`DefaultConnectionInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/DefaultConnectionInfo.cs#L78) and it's respective [`TlsConnectionInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/Features/TlsConnectionFeature.cs) it seems like there is no difference between the two, except that you can `await` the `GetClientCertificateAsync` method

Answer (score 0):

There seems that there is no difference between the two. They both return `X509Certificate2`.

- [source code for ClientCertificate](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/DefaultConnectionInfo.cs#L78)
- [source code for GetClientCertificateAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/Features/TlsConnectionFeature.cs)

The only difference is that you can `await` the `GetClientCertificateAsync` because it returnes a `Task<X509Certificate2>`and that it accepts a cancellation token.([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo.getclientcertificateasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1))

```
var certificate = await HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
```

or

```
var certificate = await HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync(cancellationToken);
```